# Can d3 pass a mouseover event to a layer underneath?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to understand something here:

I have two rectangles on top of each others. The bottom rectangle is listening for a 'mouseover' event. Half of this rectangle is covered by another rectangle.

Moving the mouse over the first rectangle the mouseover event is being triggered. Moving the mouse over the second rectangle on top no mouseover event is being triggered.

Is there a way to 'tell' the second rectangle to 'pass' the mouseover event onto the bottom (first) one?

Here is my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">


<body>
</body>

<!-- Load in the d3 library -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>

    // 2. Use the margin convention practice
    var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50}
        , width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right // Use the window's width
        , height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom; // Use the window's height


    // 1. Add the SVG to the page and employ #2
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    // first rectangle with mouse event listener 
    const first_layer = svg.append('rect').attr('x', 0).attr('y', 0).attr('width', width).attr('height', height).attr('fill', '#ff0000').on('mouseover', () => {
        console.log(d3.event.x)
    });

    // second rectangle covering half of the first rectangle, blocking the mouse event
    const second_layer = svg.append('rect').attr('x', 0).attr('y', 0).attr('width', width).attr('height', height / 2).attr('fill', '#0000ff');
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if we are not using `second_layer` for any mouse-related events, we can set its attribute of `pointer-events` to `none`. This will prevent it from reacting to any pointer events. Simply chain `.style('pointer-events', 'none')` to `second_layer` and you're all set.

```
 const second_layer = svg.append('rect').attr('x', 0).attr('y', 0).attr('width', width).style('pointer-events', 'none')......;
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, that worked a treat. Exactly what I needed!